# Docker env vars + Heroku; Heroku requires ENV while local build requires ARG

Tags: docker, heroku

My understanding of Heroku's Docker container-registry CLI was that it was a wrapper around the Docker cli.

When I build locally I'll use, for example: `docker build -f Dockerfile.example --build-arg SECRET_KEY=abc`.  And I'll have set `ARG SECRET_KEY` in my Dockerfile.example.

However if I want to push up to heroku's docker container-registry, I found out that I need to declare `ENV SECRET_KEY=abc` in my Dockerfile.example, and then run the command `heroku container:push example --recursive`.

Why is the case? What sets them apart? Isn't hardcoding the ENV bad security practice? Does Heroku offer a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run something like 
    **heroku container:push web --arg SECRET_KEY=xxxSecret123**

In that way, You don't have to feed information in your Dockerfile directly.

Comment: What about if you have heroku review and don't want to pass the arg each time a review app is create?

Answer (score 0):

The config vars (per app) override whatever values you hard-code in the Dockerfile. Put a placeholder value in your Dockerfile (personal favotite: `notsecret`) and set the actual secret values on the Heroku UI or CLI.

Comment: You mean set the secret in theconfig vars? but they are not available during the docker build as far as I understand.

Comment: That doesn't work, docker doesn't see env variables either way